# Doubt about topological neighbourhoods

Tags: general-topology

The standard topology I was taught for $\mathbb{R}$ is
$$N(x)=\{[a,b]\mid a<x<b\}$$
And a union  of neighborhoods is also a neighborhood .
But by the second axiom of the definition via neighbourhoods:

> If N is a subset of X and includes a neighbourhood of x, then N is a neighbourhood of x. I.e., every superset of a neighbourhood of a point x in X is again a neighbourhood of x.

but, it seems to say that if I add, for example, the point 6 to $[1,3]$ It is still a neighborhood of 2, but that conflicts with the definition.
What am I missing?

Comment: There is an ambiguity across authors whether a neighborhood of a point $x$ is itself an open set, or whether it is merely any set whose interior contains $x$.

Comment: @DavidKraemer, but you have to define an open set.

Comment: A valid definition for neighbourhood in $\mathbb R$ that induces the standard topology on $\mathbb R$ is: $N$ is a neighbourhood of $x\in \mathbb R$ if and only if $N'\subseteq N$ for some $N'\in N(x)$, with $N(x)$ as you have defined it.  The set of neighbourhoods of $x$ is then closed under taking supersets.

Comment: There are two conventional definitions of *neighbourhood*. They disagree. (i) a neighbourhood of $x$ is an open set with $x$ as an element. (ii) a neighbourhood of $x$ is a set containing an open set with $x$ as an element. Under definition (ii) $[1,3]\cup\{6\}$ is a neighbourhood of $2$ but not under definition (i).

Comment: To clarify further - you can induce a topology on a set by giving a set of neighbourhoods for each element: A set is open if and only if  it contains a neighbourhood of each of its elements.  However once you have done this, you can define the neighbourhood of a point as any set containing an open set containing the point.  This need not be the same set of neighbourhoods that you started with.  I think this is your confusion.  Your $N(x)$ induce the topology, but then the total set of neighbourhoods is as I described.

Comment: @bof, Sorry for the inclarity, union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $N(x)$ you gave is not the set of all neighbourhoods of $x$, its a **base** for the neighbourhoods of $x$ (in the usual topology on $\Bbb R$). This means that $U \subseteq \Bbb R$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ iff there is an $N \in N(x)$ such that $N \subseteq U$.

It's easy to check that the collection of *all* neighbourhoods of $x$ (defined from this base) does form a (co-called) filter (closed under finite intersectiosn (**not** compositions) and supersets). So $[0,3] \cup \{6\}$ is a neighbourhood of $2$ as it contains $[0,3] \in N(2)$, e.g.

Note that many books and authors define a neighbourhood of $x$ to be an open subset of $\Bbb R$ that contains $x$ and in that case $[0,3]$ is not a neighbourhood of $2$ as it's not open, as witnessed by its non-interior points $0$ and $3$. But it *is* a neighbourhood in the more relaxed sense that you seem to be using. What matters is that $x$ is in the interior of every $N(x)$ and thus in that of every neighbourhood too.